# Unity PersistentManager.WriteFile error

Tags: unity-game-engine, workflow, hard-drive, write-error

I have recently upgraded Unity to the 4.2.x series and I have run into a workflow problem that I am lost with. I have also tried this with the newest version (4.3.3f1) and I am also getting the same problem.

---

Here are the specs for my computer:

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770k CPU @ 3.50GHz

Memory: 16GB RAM

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro

Hard drives:

Main: Samsung 120GB Solid State Drive

Secondary: WD 2TB Mechanical Drive x2 on RAID ONE

---

When creating a new 2D project I select nothing except the 2D option and set it to be in my Mechanical Drive. First Error that appears is the following:

> Opening file G:/Projects/....../Temp/tempfile failed: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
>       Options:
>       Try Again|Force Quit|Cancel

I would press Try Again as nothing (not even file explorer was using that folder in anyway. It then loads up Unity with 2 errors:

> GetPersistentManager ().WriteFile (i->path, BuildTargetSelection::NoTarget(), kDontReadObjectsFromDiskBeforeWriting)

and

> container.begin () == container.end ()
>   UnityEditor.HandleUtility:BeginHandles()

This has only started happening recently and I have created two projects before this with none of these errors using 4.2.1f. Now every time I would want to create a folder it would output the GetPersistentManager error. Unity will also not allow me to drag any assets into a folder via editor (however I am able to right click and import asset and import them that way). When I try and put the asset into the folder via file explorer i receive the following error:

> Fatal Error! 
>   GetPersistentManager().WriteFileInternal(metaDataPath, metaDataFileIndex, writeData.begin(), writeData.size(), NULL, BuildTargetSelection::NoTarget(),0)

The asset I imported is a sprite sheet that I have used in the previous 2 projects stated above.

---

As a test I have also repeated this process on my primary hard drive and it still gives me the same results.

This has become a problem as now my other two projects are having the same issues as the three errors above. If anyone has any idea what might be causing this please let me know.

Comment: try deleting the `Temp` and `Library` folders inside your project folder.

Comment: @Roberto unfortunately when I delete those two folders the process repeats again. I did however manage to get this working on my Macbook Pro. but considering this computer will be my work computer I need to solve this quickly. When I open the project I had it pulled from my repository with only the ProjectSettings and Asset folder (As I ignore all the other files).

Comment: I found the problem. It was my anti-virus (Total Defense) I manually added permissions and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was my anti-virus (Total Defense) I manually added permissions and it worked

Comment: Awesome! So mark your question as correct so everyone with the same problem can easier see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, turned out to be Google Drive backup and sync syncing the project folder. 
Switched over to git with a github repo for my backup purposes. Problem solved.

Quick tip: Google unity3d gitignore. There is a lot of temp stuff in unity projects that you do not need to back up or commit, so a good git ignore file will save a lot of disk space and time.

Hope this helps someone.